# Different signs for standardized and unstandardized coefficients in linear mixed model with interaction term

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, regression-coefficients, standardization

I use R and the `lme4` package to fit a linear mixed model that includes a random intercept as well as an interaction term: `y ~ (1 | s) + a + b + c + a:b`.

Only the variable `s` is categorial.

To obtain standardized regression coefficients for the fixed effects, I refit the model with standardized data obtained via R's `scale` function, applied to the raw `y`, `a`, `b`, and `c` values.

However, some of the standardized regression coefficients obtained in this way have a different sign than the respective unstandardized coefficients.

Can this be a meaningful result, or is there something wrong with my approach to determining the standardized coefficients by scaling the data?

Comment: What are the associated standard errors?

Comment: Using `parameters::model_parameters()` and the fit resulting from the standardized data, all standard errors are within the range $[0.16,0.22]$. Perhaps it should also be mentioned that all 95% confidence intervals include $0$.

Comment: Did you scale the data or did you scale the design matrix?  My guess is you scaled the data.  Consider what effect that had on the `a:b` term.

Comment: Exactly, I scaled the data. Unfortunately, however, I can't imagine what effect this has on the `a:b` term. When I look at diagrams starting from both fits, they are slightly different, but unfortunately I don't understand the connection to the different signs.

Comment: I mean, if all 95% confidence intervals include 0, then sign reversal isn't unlikely.

Comment: @usεr11852, can you perhaps elaborate in this? Vaguely, I see the connection between "confidence interval includes 0" and "improbability of equal results" (so possibly also different signs), but not quite in this case, since the data were merely scaled.

Comment: Are you looking at the coefficients for the purpose of explanation/interpretation? That is, "one unit change of variable *a* corresponds to ..." In that case, consider making partial dependence plots which can elegantly handle the fact that *a* appears in two regression terms.